# Is it a good idea to test classes in its own main?

Tags: java, class, testing

When it comes to test your code, is it a good idea to use its own main for testing?
The other option would be to use an external file with this tests.

An example:

```
Class Foo{
    Foo(){/*...*/}
    public boolean met1(){/*...*/}
    //other metodes...

    //Tests
    public static void main(String args[]){
         Foo f = new Foo();
         //Test the correctness of data...

         boolean r = f.met1();
         //check the result...
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of this technic.
Maybe there are better approaches for testing code that i did not mention.

Comment: Not sure if it's good practice, but it's very convinient!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a test that can be truly **automated**, you should use an external file, as for JUnit etc.  Lots of support for running all the tests, continuous integration, reporting back with nice green and red lines, etc...

If it is a GUI element that you want to be able to bring up and see what it looks like, and perhaps manually click on places to see what happens, it's o.k. to use main().  Comment as such.

Likewise, if it is something complex that a programmer might want to test and watch what's going on in the debugger, vary the command line args, etc.  it's o.k. to use a main().   Comment as such.

Comment: I agree, it's mainly a question of who is running the code. You want them to run automatically by a continuous integration server if feasible. Test frameworks such as JUnit are the way to go in these cases. The other thing to consider IMHO is to make sure you don't clutter your production code with test code.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK if you want just to run your code when it was completed to check the result. 
But I prefer special Main class and call these method from it (just not to have junk code in many classes).
But anyway [JUnit](http://www.junit.org/) tests are much better.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter that much, but there is one benefit of using the main method inside the same class, which is that you can use the private static class fields of the class inside the main method.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{

    private static String someText = "blah blah";

    public Foo(){/*...*/}

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         System.out.println(someText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any cons other than making your classes larger than they need to be.  However, I would consider it wasted effort that should be put towards writing formalized tests as part of a framework that can help you avoid mistakes.